# Filter nested objects in WPGraphQL

Tags: wordpress, graphql, wp-graphql

I'm using WPGraphQL to interact with a vanilla wordpress backend. [gatsby-source-wordpress](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress) is used as a client.

What I would like to achieve with my query:

- for a list of category ids, give me a list of posts that belong to each category
- each list of posts should be filtered (posts not having a certain id, etc), and limited to a certain number. The filter/limit params would be the same for each category.

Now when I'm constructing my query, it seems like I can only filter the outer node (category), but not the attached post node:

```
// syntax from the gatsby-source-wordpress plugin
// https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress

query MyQuery {
  allWpCategory(filter: {id: {in: ["dGVybTo0Mg=="]}}) {
    nodes {
      posts { // cannot filter here 
        nodes {
          title
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried adding the filter in different locations, without success. Searched for solutions, but didn't find any specific to this GraphQL implementation. Structurally, [this](https://dgraph.io/docs/graphql/queries/search-filtering/#filter-a-query-for-a-list-of-objects) looks like what I'm try to achieve, but it's a different platform altogether.

My questions:

- is it possible to get this working (it seems like a pretty standard requirement to me)
- if yes, how
- if no, what's the limiting factor? (GraphQL, WPGraphQL, gatsby-source-wordpress)

Comment: Hi, did You use Gatsbys GraphiQL?

Comment: Yes, that's my primary way of constructing queries right now. Taking a loot at your proposed solution 

Comment: If You expand the filter section in GraphiQL, doesn't it show the path down to posts ... node ... id?

Comment: Have you tried using the post's database ID instead of the relay ID?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your data structure and can't test. Does something like this work?

```
query MyQuery {
  allWpCategory(
        filter: {
            posts: {
                elemMatch: {
                    id: {
                        ne: "something"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                id: {
                    in: ["dGVybTo0Mg=="]
                }
            }
        })
    {
        nodes {
            posts { // cannot filter here 
                nodes {
                    title
                    id
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't do what I need. It returns those categories that have associated posts which match the filter. In your example (ignoring the `id` filter): please return all categories that have at least one post with an `id` not equal to `something`. This makes sense, since the `filter` is happening on the `category` level.

Comment: I see. Interesting. Sorry, not good enough with GraphQL. But curious about a solution. I remember stumbling over similar needs. The datasets weren't too big. So I ended up using JavaScrips map/reduce to get what I required.

Comment: Yes, I'll probably end up doing the same. Feels pretty weird though, since this seems like a common enough requirement. Thanks a lot anyway for taking the time. Maybe there'll be a working answer eventually.